# disable scrolling of main content when scrollable sidebar is open

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, scrollbar, sidebar

I have a website with a sidebar that can be opened, overlapping the main content. The sidebar can be opened by using translate-x... or setting its width to 100%, doesn't matter.

The problem: when the sidebar overlapps the main content you get 2 scrollbars, one for the sidebar and one for the main content.

I want to disable scrolling on the main element when the sidebar is open (e.g. width 100%).

Here a simple demo-code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
    background-color: #2980b9;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    width: 18%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#content {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    width: 82%;
    overflow: auto;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <!-- Sidebar contents -->
        <div id="sidebar-content" style="height: 2800px"></div>
    </div><!--
 --><div id="content">
        <!-- Main contents -->
        <div id="main-content" style="height: 1800px">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should put this in a snippet so that it's easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. You will need to have a simple jQuery function that will lock the background to prevent scrolling while your sidebar is visible.

By setting `html` and `body` to `margin:0; height:100%; overflow:hidden` you will effectively prevent scrolling.

If you provide more specifics I can get more detailed if I need to. Hope this helps!

```js
$('#btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.sidebar').toggleClass('slide');
  $('html body').toggleClass('lock');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ececec;
  padding: 40px;
  p {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 20px auto;
  }
}

#btn {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: indianred;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 1400px;
  background: #007ccc;
  width: 400px;
  max-height: 600px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: transform ease .5s;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.slide {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.lock {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id="btn">CLICK ME</button>
  <div class="main">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dolor risus, placerat vel justo non, ultricies dignissim dui. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum dignissim enim a sem dapibus faucibus. Cras egestas erat non tellus ullamcorper, at rhoncus
      lacus placerat. Aenean in orci velit. Aliquam dapibus dignissim rutrum. Suspendisse vel sapien justo. Praesent ante nisl, fermentum facilisis ante quis, convallis congue justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
    </p>
    <p>
      In at suscipit augue. In fermentum hendrerit libero, et placerat odio tempus eu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean eu mattis erat. Aliquam vitae interdum velit. Proin vitae elit quis leo
      condimentum accumsan. Fusce id lorem felis. Sed in arcu in purus tristique tempor ac nec augue. Donec pellentesque nibh rutrum velit ornare, quis tempor nisi vehicula. Sed mollis est sed felis scelerisque, sed porttitor nisi tempor. Suspendisse
      eu eros eget augue aliquet bibendum non eu dui.
    </p>
    <p>

      Phasellus eu blandit elit, non elementum orci. Cras neque urna, laoreet eu sem eu, faucibus blandit massa. Curabitur sit amet tincidunt metus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc quis lectus
      egestas, pulvinar mi vitae, fermentum sapien. Praesent iaculis, quam accumsan facilisis interdum, ligula ante sagittis nunc, id hendrerit odio lacus sed ex. Phasellus massa felis, aliquet quis imperdiet sodales, maximus in sapien.
    </p>
    <p>

      Morbi aliquam tristique ligula, eu pulvinar odio pretium sed. Nulla tincidunt sit amet velit eget consectetur. Aenean eros arcu, gravida a viverra eu, rutrum eu nunc. Nulla et nunc tristique, vestibulum eros ut, venenatis mauris. Integer eleifend a lorem
      eget tempor. Aliquam lacinia sed risus non rhoncus. Sed viverra mauris non molestie dignissim.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vivamus blandit, turpis id malesuada commodo, mauris purus cursus erat, in tincidunt mi quam at est. Suspendisse pharetra tempus laoreet. Suspendisse mollis odio in mi sollicitudin volutpat. Donec non nibh mollis, aliquet turpis in, rutrum justo. In sagittis
      ac tortor vitae venenatis. Aenean vestibulum urna sit amet tempor sagittis. Cras accumsan bibendum bibendum. Etiam tristique neque purus, convallis cursus lorem hendrerit nec. Nam rutrum, lectus sed finibus viverra, leo augue fermentum est, et varius
      metus erat sed odio. Sed ultrices posuere aliquam. Suspendisse egestas tincidunt augue id tempus. Proin vel molestie mauris. Nunc in malesuada orci. Phasellus at euismod quam. Praesent pretium varius nibh id rutrum. Donec posuere enim libero, vel
      porta ante consequat ac.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dolor risus, placerat vel justo non, ultricies dignissim dui. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum dignissim enim a sem dapibus faucibus. Cras egestas erat non tellus ullamcorper, at rhoncus
      lacus placerat. Aenean in orci velit. Aliquam dapibus dignissim rutrum. Suspendisse vel sapien justo. Praesent ante nisl, fermentum facilisis ante quis, convallis congue justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
    </p>
    <p>
      In at suscipit augue. In fermentum hendrerit libero, et placerat odio tempus eu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean eu mattis erat. Aliquam vitae interdum velit. Proin vitae elit quis leo
      condimentum accumsan. Fusce id lorem felis. Sed in arcu in purus tristique tempor ac nec augue. Donec pellentesque nibh rutrum velit ornare, quis tempor nisi vehicula. Sed mollis est sed felis scelerisque, sed porttitor nisi tempor. Suspendisse
      eu eros eget augue aliquet bibendum non eu dui.
    </p>
    <p>

      Phasellus eu blandit elit, non elementum orci. Cras neque urna, laoreet eu sem eu, faucibus blandit massa. Curabitur sit amet tincidunt metus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc quis lectus
      egestas, pulvinar mi vitae, fermentum sapien. Praesent iaculis, quam accumsan facilisis interdum, ligula ante sagittis nunc, id hendrerit odio lacus sed ex. Phasellus massa felis, aliquet quis imperdiet sodales, maximus in sapien.
    </p>
    <p>

      Morbi aliquam tristique ligula, eu pulvinar odio pretium sed. Nulla tincidunt sit amet velit eget consectetur. Aenean eros arcu, gravida a viverra eu, rutrum eu nunc. Nulla et nunc tristique, vestibulum eros ut, venenatis mauris. Integer eleifend a lorem
      eget tempor. Aliquam lacinia sed risus non rhoncus. Sed viverra mauris non molestie dignissim.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vivamus blandit, turpis id malesuada commodo, mauris purus cursus erat, in tincidunt mi quam at est. Suspendisse pharetra tempus laoreet. Suspendisse mollis odio in mi sollicitudin volutpat. Donec non nibh mollis, aliquet turpis in, rutrum justo. In sagittis
      ac tortor vitae venenatis. Aenean vestibulum urna sit amet tempor sagittis. Cras accumsan bibendum bibendum. Etiam tristique neque purus, convallis cursus lorem hendrerit nec. Nam rutrum, lectus sed finibus viverra, leo augue fermentum est, et varius
      metus erat sed odio. Sed ultrices posuere aliquam. Suspendisse egestas tincidunt augue id tempus. Proin vel molestie mauris. Nunc in malesuada orci. Phasellus at euismod quam. Praesent pretium varius nibh id rutrum. Donec posuere enim libero, vel
      porta ante consequat ac.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dolor risus, placerat vel justo non, ultricies dignissim dui. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum dignissim enim a sem dapibus faucibus. Cras egestas erat non tellus ullamcorper, at rhoncus
      lacus placerat. Aenean in orci velit. Aliquam dapibus dignissim rutrum. Suspendisse vel sapien justo. Praesent ante nisl, fermentum facilisis ante quis, convallis congue justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
    </p>
    <p>
      In at suscipit augue. In fermentum hendrerit libero, et placerat odio tempus eu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean eu mattis erat. Aliquam vitae interdum velit. Proin vitae elit quis leo
      condimentum accumsan. Fusce id lorem felis. Sed in arcu in purus tristique tempor ac nec augue. Donec pellentesque nibh rutrum velit ornare, quis tempor nisi vehicula. Sed mollis est sed felis scelerisque, sed porttitor nisi tempor. Suspendisse
      eu eros eget augue aliquet bibendum non eu dui.
    </p>
    <p>

      Phasellus eu blandit elit, non elementum orci. Cras neque urna, laoreet eu sem eu, faucibus blandit massa. Curabitur sit amet tincidunt metus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc quis lectus
      egestas, pulvinar mi vitae, fermentum sapien. Praesent iaculis, quam accumsan facilisis interdum, ligula ante sagittis nunc, id hendrerit odio lacus sed ex. Phasellus massa felis, aliquet quis imperdiet sodales, maximus in sapien.
    </p>
    <p>

      Morbi aliquam tristique ligula, eu pulvinar odio pretium sed. Nulla tincidunt sit amet velit eget consectetur. Aenean eros arcu, gravida a viverra eu, rutrum eu nunc. Nulla et nunc tristique, vestibulum eros ut, venenatis mauris. Integer eleifend a lorem
      eget tempor. Aliquam lacinia sed risus non rhoncus. Sed viverra mauris non molestie dignissim.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vivamus blandit, turpis id malesuada commodo, mauris purus cursus erat, in tincidunt mi quam at est. Suspendisse pharetra tempus laoreet. Suspendisse mollis odio in mi sollicitudin volutpat. Donec non nibh mollis, aliquet turpis in, rutrum justo. In sagittis
      ac tortor vitae venenatis. Aenean vestibulum urna sit amet tempor sagittis. Cras accumsan bibendum bibendum. Etiam tristique neque purus, convallis cursus lorem hendrerit nec. Nam rutrum, lectus sed finibus viverra, leo augue fermentum est, et varius
      metus erat sed odio. Sed ultrices posuere aliquam. Suspendisse egestas tincidunt augue id tempus. Proin vel molestie mauris. Nunc in malesuada orci. Phasellus at euismod quam. Praesent pretium varius nibh id rutrum. Donec posuere enim libero, vel
      porta ante consequat ac.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dolor risus, placerat vel justo non, ultricies dignissim dui. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum dignissim enim a sem dapibus faucibus. Cras egestas erat non tellus ullamcorper, at rhoncus
      lacus placerat. Aenean in orci velit. Aliquam dapibus dignissim rutrum. Suspendisse vel sapien justo. Praesent ante nisl, fermentum facilisis ante quis, convallis congue justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
    </p>
    <p>
      In at suscipit augue. In fermentum hendrerit libero, et placerat odio tempus eu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean eu mattis erat. Aliquam vitae interdum velit. Proin vitae elit quis leo
      condimentum accumsan. Fusce id lorem felis. Sed in arcu in purus tristique tempor ac nec augue. Donec pellentesque nibh rutrum velit ornare, quis tempor nisi vehicula. Sed mollis est sed felis scelerisque, sed porttitor nisi tempor. Suspendisse
      eu eros eget augue aliquet bibendum non eu dui.
    </p>
    <p>

      Phasellus eu blandit elit, non elementum orci. Cras neque urna, laoreet eu sem eu, faucibus blandit massa. Curabitur sit amet tincidunt metus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc quis lectus
      egestas, pulvinar mi vitae, fermentum sapien. Praesent iaculis, quam accumsan facilisis interdum, ligula ante sagittis nunc, id hendrerit odio lacus sed ex. Phasellus massa felis, aliquet quis imperdiet sodales, maximus in sapien.
    </p>
    <p>

      Morbi aliquam tristique ligula, eu pulvinar odio pretium sed. Nulla tincidunt sit amet velit eget consectetur. Aenean eros arcu, gravida a viverra eu, rutrum eu nunc. Nulla et nunc tristique, vestibulum eros ut, venenatis mauris. Integer eleifend a lorem
      eget tempor. Aliquam lacinia sed risus non rhoncus. Sed viverra mauris non molestie dignissim.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vivamus blandit, turpis id malesuada commodo, mauris purus cursus erat, in tincidunt mi quam at est. Suspendisse pharetra tempus laoreet. Suspendisse mollis odio in mi sollicitudin volutpat. Donec non nibh mollis, aliquet turpis in, rutrum justo. In sagittis
      ac tortor vitae venenatis. Aenean vestibulum urna sit amet tempor sagittis. Cras accumsan bibendum bibendum. Etiam tristique neque purus, convallis cursus lorem hendrerit nec. Nam rutrum, lectus sed finibus viverra, leo augue fermentum est, et varius
      metus erat sed odio. Sed ultrices posuere aliquam. Suspendisse egestas tincidunt augue id tempus. Proin vel molestie mauris. Nunc in malesuada orci. Phasellus at euismod quam. Praesent pretium varius nibh id rutrum. Donec posuere enim libero, vel
      porta ante consequat ac.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dolor risus, placerat vel justo non, ultricies dignissim dui. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum dignissim enim a sem dapibus faucibus. Cras egestas erat non tellus ullamcorper, at rhoncus
      lacus placerat. Aenean in orci velit. Aliquam dapibus dignissim rutrum. Suspendisse vel sapien justo. Praesent ante nisl, fermentum facilisis ante quis, convallis congue justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
    </p>
    <p>
      In at suscipit augue. In fermentum hendrerit libero, et placerat odio tempus eu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean eu mattis erat. Aliquam vitae interdum velit. Proin vitae elit quis leo
      condimentum accumsan. Fusce id lorem felis. Sed in arcu in purus tristique tempor ac nec augue. Donec pellentesque nibh rutrum velit ornare, quis tempor nisi vehicula. Sed mollis est sed felis scelerisque, sed porttitor nisi tempor. Suspendisse
      eu eros eget augue aliquet bibendum non eu dui.
    </p>
    <p>

      Phasellus eu blandit elit, non elementum orci. Cras neque urna, laoreet eu sem eu, faucibus blandit massa. Curabitur sit amet tincidunt metus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc quis lectus
      egestas, pulvinar mi vitae, fermentum sapien. Praesent iaculis, quam accumsan facilisis interdum, ligula ante sagittis nunc, id hendrerit odio lacus sed ex. Phasellus massa felis, aliquet quis imperdiet sodales, maximus in sapien.
    </p>
    <p>

      Morbi aliquam tristique ligula, eu pulvinar odio pretium sed. Nulla tincidunt sit amet velit eget consectetur. Aenean eros arcu, gravida a viverra eu, rutrum eu nunc. Nulla et nunc tristique, vestibulum eros ut, venenatis mauris. Integer eleifend a lorem
      eget tempor. Aliquam lacinia sed risus non rhoncus. Sed viverra mauris non molestie dignissim.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vivamus blandit, turpis id malesuada commodo, mauris purus cursus erat, in tincidunt mi quam at est. Suspendisse pharetra tempus laoreet. Suspendisse mollis odio in mi sollicitudin volutpat. Donec non nibh mollis, aliquet turpis in, rutrum justo. In sagittis
      ac tortor vitae venenatis. Aenean vestibulum urna sit amet tempor sagittis. Cras accumsan bibendum bibendum. Etiam tristique neque purus, convallis cursus lorem hendrerit nec. Nam rutrum, lectus sed finibus viverra, leo augue fermentum est, et varius
      metus erat sed odio. Sed ultrices posuere aliquam. Suspendisse egestas tincidunt augue id tempus. Proin vel molestie mauris. Nunc in malesuada orci. Phasellus at euismod quam. Praesent pretium varius nibh id rutrum. Donec posuere enim libero, vel
      porta ante consequat ac.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus dolor risus, placerat vel justo non, ultricies dignissim dui. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum dignissim enim a sem dapibus faucibus. Cras egestas erat non tellus ullamcorper, at rhoncus
      lacus placerat. Aenean in orci velit. Aliquam dapibus dignissim rutrum. Suspendisse vel sapien justo. Praesent ante nisl, fermentum facilisis ante quis, convallis congue justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
    </p>
    <p>
      In at suscipit augue. In fermentum hendrerit libero, et placerat odio tempus eu. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean eu mattis erat. Aliquam vitae interdum velit. Proin vitae elit quis leo
      condimentum accumsan. Fusce id lorem felis. Sed in arcu in purus tristique tempor ac nec augue. Donec pellentesque nibh rutrum velit ornare, quis tempor nisi vehicula. Sed mollis est sed felis scelerisque, sed porttitor nisi tempor. Suspendisse
      eu eros eget augue aliquet bibendum non eu dui.
    </p>
    <p>

      Phasellus eu blandit elit, non elementum orci. Cras neque urna, laoreet eu sem eu, faucibus blandit massa. Curabitur sit amet tincidunt metus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nunc quis lectus
      egestas, pulvinar mi vitae, fermentum sapien. Praesent iaculis, quam accumsan facilisis interdum, ligula ante sagittis nunc, id hendrerit odio lacus sed ex. Phasellus massa felis, aliquet quis imperdiet sodales, maximus in sapien.
    </p>
    <p>

      Morbi aliquam tristique ligula, eu pulvinar odio pretium sed. Nulla tincidunt sit amet velit eget consectetur. Aenean eros arcu, gravida a viverra eu, rutrum eu nunc. Nulla et nunc tristique, vestibulum eros ut, venenatis mauris. Integer eleifend a lorem
      eget tempor. Aliquam lacinia sed risus non rhoncus. Sed viverra mauris non molestie dignissim.
    </p>
    <p>
      Vivamus blandit, turpis id malesuada commodo, mauris purus cursus erat, in tincidunt mi quam at est. Suspendisse pharetra tempus laoreet. Suspendisse mollis odio in mi sollicitudin volutpat. Donec non nibh mollis, aliquet turpis in, rutrum justo. In sagittis
      ac tortor vitae venenatis. Aenean vestibulum urna sit amet tempor sagittis. Cras accumsan bibendum bibendum. Etiam tristique neque purus, convallis cursus lorem hendrerit nec. Nam rutrum, lectus sed finibus viverra, leo augue fermentum est, et varius
      metus erat sed odio. Sed ultrices posuere aliquam. Suspendisse egestas tincidunt augue id tempus. Proin vel molestie mauris. Nunc in malesuada orci. Phasellus at euismod quam. Praesent pretium varius nibh id rutrum. Donec posuere enim libero, vel
      porta ante consequat ac.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. It does work, although it is a big jumpy, I think that's due to the main content scrollbar appearing and disappearing. From those 3 lines of CSS only this here seems to be necessary: overflow: hidden;. Or do I really need the margin as well? It seems to work without setting margin to 0.